# Coldfusion calculate seconds in days, hours, min

Tags: date, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I want to convert seconds to days, hours and minutes
Currently, it works just for hours and minutes but not for days. Can you please support me tell me what I did wrong:

```
<cfscript>
    seconds = '87400';
    midnight = CreateTime(0,0,0);
    time = DateAdd("s", seconds, variables.midnight);
    date= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx???
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
    #DateFormat(variables.date, 'd')#  not working 
    #TimeFormat(variables.time, 'HH:mm')#
</cfoutput>
```

For the value `87400` the expected result is

- 1 Days, 0 hours, 16 minutes

If I take `94152` seconds it will be:

- 1 days, 3 hours, 22 minutes

The only issue i have is to get the correct days ... hours and minutes are diplayed but not the correct days

thank you for all the support

Comment: Could you elaborate on what result you're expecting for 87400 seconds?

Comment: @SOS thx for the reply. sure for 87400  is 1 Days 0 hours 16 minutes 

if i take 94152 seconds it will be:  1 days 3 hours 22 minutes 

the only issue i have is to get the correct days ...  hours and minutes are diplayed but not the correct days

Comment: The simplest way is using modulus.  See my example. (FWIW, for the second value, it should be 2 hours not 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand from your question that you don't need to get a certain date and time along a timeline, but convert a total amount of seconds in days, hours and minutes. To do that you don't necessary need to use cfml time and date functions like CreateTime() or DateAdd(). You just may need these in order to get a reference point of time or date along a timeline, which doesn't seem to be the case, otherwise you would know the value of your starting `date` variable. Thus, you can solve this with plain rule of three. There may be simpler methods, so I'm posting an alternative only.

We know that:

```
    60 seconds is equivalent to 1 minute
    60 minutes is equivalent to 1 hour
    24 hours is equivalent to 1 day
```

Thus, your calcualtion within cfml could be like so:

```javascript
<cfscript>
    //Constants for calculation
    secondsPerDay= 60*60*24;
    secondsPerHour= 60*60;
    secondsPerMinute= 60;

    //Seconds to convert
    secondsTotal=87400;
     
    // temp variable
    secondsRemain= secondsTotal;
    
    days= int( secondsRemain / secondsPerDay);
    secondsRemain= secondsRemain - days * secondsPerDay;
    hours= int( secondsRemain / secondsPerHour);
    secondsRemain= secondsRemain - hours * secondsPerHour;
    minutes= int( secondsRemain / secondsPerMinute);
    secondsRemain= secondsRemain - minutes * secondsPerMinute;

    writeoutput( "#secondsTotal# seconds are: #days# days, #hours# hours, #minutes# minutes and #secondsRemain# seconds." );

</cfscript>
```

That outputs:

```
87400 seconds are: 1 days, 0 hours, 16 minutes and 40 seconds.
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to calculate the intervals is by taking advantage of the [modulus operator](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-expressions-and-number-signs/expressions-developing-guide.html):

```
totalSeconds  = 94152;
days = int(totalSeconds / 86400); 
hours = totalSeconds / 3600 % 24; 
minutes = totalSeconds / 60 % 60; 
seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
```

For `94152` seconds, the results would be:

| Interval | Value |
| --- | --- |
| DAYS | 1 |
| HOURS | 2 |
| MINUTES | 9 |
| SECONDS | 12 |
| TOTALSECONDS | 94152 |

[demo trycf.com](https://trycf.com/gist/a2edd7fb0fe7accff5cb2e5441a06ee9/acf2021?theme=monokai)

Comment: I just upvoted your answer, because using modulus is way shorter and simpler than mine.

Comment: Thanks. Well a lot of your code is explanatory stuff, which is never a bad thing!